# Space complexity of a B-tree index in a database

Tags: database, algorithm, data-structures, b-tree, space-complexity

A traditional B-tree implementation has O(n) space complexity [[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree)].

So assume in a database (regardless of implementation, just consider general case), I have a table of 10GB data, currently the index size is 1GB, so can I assume that if the database grown to 100GB, my index size will be 10GB?

Comment: Size of the index, will be proportional to your index column!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot say anything "regardless of implementation."

If the index is a pure B-tree, then it *theoretically should* be linear in the number and size of keys being indexed with some fudge factor for fill rates.  However, it is unlikely to be a pure B-tree.  First, it might be a B+tree or some other variant. B+tree would add a very small logarithmic term to the size computation.  That increase is unlikely to be material.  More importantly, most implementations do not implement theoretical B-tree operations to maintain the fill rate.  For example, deletion might be implemented by merely leaving an open slot to be used by a later insert.  Over a large number of operations and with a bit of bad luck, the efficiency of the index representation can degrade so the index might get larger.  If your index on 10GB is tightly packed and your 100GB is after a year of operations, it might be larger than you expect.

In direct answer to your question - no I do not think your assumption is safe.   More because the index might change size over time than due to non-linearity in the underlying data structure.